# Wheres the datagridview in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I just started playing around with WPF today, and I couldn't find the datagridview control.  What gives?  Is it called something else?  Please help a very confused individual.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no built-in `DataGrid` for WPF. However, they have released an MS-supported one on CodeProject. Check [this](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx) out.

Comment: Alright ill try it out.  I'm assuming I have to download this whole tookit thing off that site?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .Net 4.0 - you have the DataGrid which is the equivalent of the DataGridView. (And it is essentially the same as the 3.5sp1 CTP Charlie links to)

Answer (score 1):

there is a built in data grid for wpf in .net 3/3.5,
it just called ListView..
and you need to tell him that his default view is GridView(built in view type of list view)

it does not have many capabilities and thats why WPFToolkit implemented a DataGrid control